# Facing issues in clob data type in oracle 11g and some special characters are not migrating properly

Tags: oracle11g, database-migration

I am working on a project which is having oracle 11g as database. Actually we are migrating old project i.e which is developed using visualbasic and foxpro as database.
while migrating old data from foxpro to our oracle table the columns having long description containing special characters are not migrating properly.
I am using one tool named fox to oracle migration which is developed by internal java team.
My question is how to solve this issue .
Special characters means like @,^ & and.....

My Second question is we are having long description more than 4000 characters. I am planing to take clob datatype for those columns will it be fine?

Advance thanks..

Comment: " special characters are not migrating properly" . please expand on this. what do you mean by not migrating properly? are they missing, or translated into a different character. are the source foxpro character set and your oracle DB character set the same too?

Comment: Hi Dazzal,"Special characters are not migrating properly" means in foxpro the special characters are present but after migrationg those characters are not present in our migrated tables.